# Hash type in Oracle db?

Tags: oracle, passwords

I am looking at a Oracle db user password, which is in the format:

```
27-char password followed by '='
```

example (not-real)

```
ABCDEFghijklMNOPQRstuvwx/+5=
```

I am **NOT** looking for guidance on password cracking tools.

My questions here are:

**First**: Core question is with knowledge of this password, how can I identify/confirm if the pass is indeed hashed / encrypted

**Second**: If the above 27-char password is indeed hashed/encrypted, how can I check if this is done using Oracle's in-built hashing/enc functions

**Third**: Is there a way I can reverse the encrypted password using in-built function itself?

Comment: What "password field" are we talking about?  Are we talking about how the Oracle database stores passwords for Oracle database users?  Or are we talking about how some application stores passwords for application users?

Comment: The former.. how oracle stores (securely) db user passwords. Whether the password value I have is a hash or encrypted format? How can I confirm that the strength of the password I have is good?

Comment: OK.  What is the business problem that you are trying to solve.  If you want to enforce particular password complexity requirements (n characters minimum, 1 upper, differ from the prior password by more than 2 characters, etc.) you can define a password complexity function.  If you want to force passwords to expire, you can use a profile.  The algorithm Oracle uses to generate the password hash is documented (and is known to be not the greatest in the world) but I'm not comfortable providing instructions for how to crack the password.

Comment: Yes, the requirement is offline pw cracking. I need to validate if the passes configured by admins meets pw security practices. I know the tools etc but need a nudge on oracle part.

Comment: Why would you need to crack the passwords in order to validate that they meet the security requirements?  Wouldn't it make more sense to validate that the password complexity requirements, the password expiration requirements, etc. are adequate?

Comment: yes, for auditing, that approach works. For testing, I should attempt to crack them.

Comment: So, I am aiming to try crack the pass within a defined time period. What I am not sure, in the first place, if the pass is hashed / encrypted in some way. In case it is encrypted using any in-built function, I guess I can simply decrypt it & re-encrypt it later..

Comment: As I said, the algorithm and various password cracking utilities are available if you search online.  I'm not comfortable providing instructions in this sort of forum on how to crack database passwords so I'll bow out of this question now.

Comment: I do not ask on how to crack passwords. I only ask on how to identify/ensure if a pass is indeed hashed / encrypted, and if it is, how best to reverse it. Thanks for your help still.

Comment: How does "reversing a hash" differ from "cracking a password"?  You're trying to crack the actual password that is stored in Oracle's password hash.  There are possibly reasonable reasons to want to do that.  But I'm not comfortable driving traffic to the sites that build those sorts of tools.

Comment: You still are not looking at my core question: By looking at password I have, how do I ensure if it is hashed vs encrypted at all.? I repeat I am not asking on *how* to use a tool. My question is a conceptual one on oracle hashing/encryption process.

Comment: Edited my question. Hope you can understand it better now. Thanks.

Comment: Can you put it off the hold now please?

Comment: Perhaps you should speak to Oracle directly - e.g. via your support rep. I agree with Justin, it's not appropriate to post this sort of info here.

Comment: Where are you getting this password?  You've said that you are looking at the way that Oracle is storing Oracle database passwords.  But that would either be in the `user$.password` column if you're looking at the old 10g and earlier hash or in the `user$.spare4` column if you're looking at the new 11g hash.  You say the hash you're looking at is 27 characters.  But these columns have 16 and 60 characters (62 if you include the leading S:).

Comment: Seriously guys, if you don't want to help, then don't. At least save your comments. I do not know why you can't help explain what I am asking. Nobody is asking you to talk on sensitive topic here. But you just keep looping around on why's & where's.

Comment: Check my First question please. First: Core question is with knowledge of this password, how can I identify/confirm if the pass is indeed hashed / encrypted

Comment: @JustinCave I said I have one Oracle db user password in a 27-char(=) format. I am trying to know if this is hashed / encrypted or not. That's the basic, first question. There are 3 questions. You can take them separately. And please don't answer third, if you are worried about any sensitive talk here.

Comment: You've said you're talking about how Oracle stores passwords for database users.  I'm asking which password hash you're talking about.  Oracle stores two different password hashes, one for 10.2 and prior compatibility and one for 11.1 and later.  Neither are 27 characters.  If we don't know where the password you're talking about is coming from, we can't possibly answer any of your questions.

Comment: Okay. This is Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit. The table is a user-defined table keeping user & passes.

Comment: OK.  So you are not asking how Oracle stores passwords for Oracle database users, then.  You are asking how some application stores passwords for application users.  Oracle would have nothing to do with how an application chooses to store passwords, whether it hashes or encrypts the password, what algorithm it uses, etc.  You'd need to talk with whoever wrote the application in question.